# Q_INVOKABLE method returning custom C++ type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ method made Q_INVOKABLE. I can call this method from QML and it works when it returns basic types (like QString). But I can't with a custom type. How should I do this? Should I return a QVariant instead? Ideally, I would like to return a pointer to my custom type if possible.

**EDIT**
I do:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyType>("Mine", 1, 0, "MyType");
qmlEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("testObj", new MyType());
```

I can use testObj global object or create MyType QML component. But I cannot use it in some javascript code as a return type from a Q_INVOKABLE C++ method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `QVariant` is the way to go for your custom class in that construction. Make sure you register your class.

That being said, you may wish to consider using Q_PROPERTY instead, for your custom type and then you can access that even without a function call. If you need custom parameters to the method and you cannot rearrange the code, this is obviously not an option.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try with QVariant then. Also, thanks for the suggestion about using Q_PROPERTY instead. In my case, the method call is to retrieve an object so a property would make perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: According to the documentation, it should be possible to return custom C++ types from a Q_INVOKABLE method to QML. Is it possible or is it a bug in the documentation?

Comment: @Korchkidu: it is possible if you properly register the type, I think.

Comment: Well, I can register the type, create a global object of this custom C++ type with setContextProperty(), use it in QML. I cannot however return this type from a Q_INVOKABLE method...

Comment: You can [if it is properly registered to QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-typesystem-objecttypes.html#defining-object-types-from-c).

Comment: It is registered because I can use it. See my edits please. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Anyway, QVariant seems to work fine and that way, I can pass return type to QML engine and JS engine. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is possible but you need to define your custom type
as an [interface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterInterface).

First of all in your **main()** function:

```
qmlRegisterInterface<MyType>("MyType");
```

Now you can proceed to create an object and return a pointer 
in a `Q_INVOKABLE`:

```
MyType* example = new MyType(parent);
return example;
```

**Note:** it might be beneficial to pass the parent to your custom QObject to ensure that this object is deleted together with his parent (to avoid memory leaks).

Comment: If nullptr parent is provided, the object is deleted when it goes out of scope in the qml code, so there is no memory leak either. If an actual parent is provided, then the object is deleted together with its parent. However, this is based on my experimenting only; I didn't find any guarantee of this behavior in the documentation.

Comment: That is actually documented here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership

Answer (score 2):

*Note that the target of this answer are people with a similar problem, rather than the original asker.*

The described method should work, at least in recent versions of Qt (I'm using Qt 5.12, but it should work in older versions too). Maybe it was a bug in one of the first QML releases.

**Checklist**: Verify you have done the following:

- Registered your type [`qmlRegisterType<MyType>("Mine", 1, 0, "MyType");`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) (or use [qmlRegisterUncreatableType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterUncreatableType))
- Imported your custom types in qml: `import Mine 1.0`
- Derived your class from QObject.
- Added `Q_OBJECT` to your class definition.

When returning pointers from a `Q_INVOKABLE` method, please take [**object ownership**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership) into account.

Answer (score 1):

I think Dimitri's answer only applies when your type is copyable (so it wouldn't work for QObject). My understanding is that when you have a type that is being manipulated by Qt, for example if it is being returned by an invokable, the type has to be registered as a [metatype](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details):

- Non-copyable types like any QObject derived model cannot be metatypes
- A pointer type is a different type, therefore it needs to register separately from the classes it points to
- For pointer type `Foo*` you can register it with metatype system: `qRegisterMetaType<Foo*>("Foo*");`