# Why is the custom QObject returned by my Q_INVOKABLE method undefined in my QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a MasterController QObject with a Q_INVOKABLE method that returns a const reference to an object of MyType, another type derived from QObject.  I register both in main().  I instantiate a MasterController and add it to the root context in main as well.  In my QML, I import the registered module containing the two derived QObject types.  In the QML, I can call into the MasterController method.  I see it going in there in the debugger.  But, when execution returns to the QML code, the returned variable is 'undefined'.  So, I can't read any of its properites.  I read the question and answers for [Q_INVOKABLE method returning custom C++ type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414873/q-invokable-method-returning-custom-c-type).  But, it it did not give me enough information to get this right.

MyType.h

```
#ifndef MYTYPE_H
#define MYTYPE_H

#include <QObject>

#include <testqt-lib_global.h>

namespace testqt {
namespace models {

class TESTQTLIB_EXPORT MyType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int ui_height READ height )
    Q_PROPERTY( int ui_width READ width )

public:
    explicit MyType(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int height() const;
    int width() const;

private:
    int _height = 2;
    int _width = 3;
};

} // namespace models
} // namespace testqt

#endif // MYTTYPE_H
```

MyType.cpp

```
#include "mytype.h"

namespace testqt {
namespace models {

MyType::MyType(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

int MyType::height() const
{
    return _height;
}

int MyType::width() const
{
    return _width;
}

} // namespace models
} // namespace testqt
```

MasterController.h

```
#ifndef MASTERCONTROLLER_H
#define MASTERCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>

#include "testqt-lib_global.h"
#include "mytype.h"

namespace testqt {
namespace controllers {

class TESTQTLIB_EXPORT MasterController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MasterController(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MasterController();

    Q_INVOKABLE const models::MyType& getData() const;

private:
    models::MyType _myData;
};

} // namespace controllers
} // namespace testqt

#endif // MASTERCONTROLLER_H
```

MasterController.cpp

```
#include "mastercontroller.h"

namespace testqt {
namespace controllers {

MasterController::MasterController(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

MasterController::~MasterController()
{
}

const models::MyType& MasterController::getData() const
{
    return _myData;
}

} // namespace controllers
} // namespace testqt
```

main.cpp (mostly boiler-plate)

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "mastercontroller.h"
#include "mytype.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<testqt::models::MyType>("TestQt", 1, 0, "MyType");
    qmlRegisterType<testqt::controllers::MasterController>("TestQt", 1, 0, "MasterController");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    testqt::controllers::MasterController masterController;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("masterController", &masterController);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import TestQt 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("testqt")

    Text {
        id: heightLabel
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        text: "height unknown"
    }

    Text {
        id: widthLabel
        anchors.top: heightLabel.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        text: "width unknown"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var data = masterController.getData();
        if (data)  // data always undefined
        {
            heightLabel.text = data.height.toString();
            widthLabel.text = data.width.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious if it works if you change your invokable function to return a pointer instead of a const ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QObjects are not copyable so you cannot pass the reference of a QObject but rather the pointer:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QObject* getData();
```

```cpp
QObject *MasterController::getData()
{
    return &_myData;
}
```

Comment: If I change the return type to a (non-const) MyType pointer as you suggest, then the "var data = masterController.getData();" call in main.qml fails entirely.  The application output window in the Qt Creator debugger says "Error: Unknown method return type: models::MyType*".

Comment: Changing the getData return type to QObject* does work.  I could have sworn I saw examples using the custom type for the return type.  But, I guess I'm not losing anything by using QObject* instead.  Thanks!